# Cost function in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, svm

I've followed the Machine Learning course of Andrew Ng, and I really confuse in Support Vector Machine lecture. Regarding cost function in SVM, he said that *when C is very large, the loss (error) equal to 0*. Can you guys help me to explain why is that?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C$ is very large, in order to reduce the cost, the term that is multiplied with $C$ should be very small, e.g. in the extreme case, if $C$ is infinite, then the other term should be $0$, otherwise the cost will be infinity.

Consider the following simple cost function:

$$J(\theta)=C\theta+f(\theta)$$

If $C$ is very very large, the optimization algorithm doesn't care about the second term much and tries to minimize the first one, e.g. $\theta$ will be close o $0$.

Comment: So, does it also mean if C increase, it'll lead to cost increase and underfitting, and if C decrease, then cost'll decrease and overfitting?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: thank you so much.